# No permitir borrar los decimales del input tipo text

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un input tipo text

```html
<input type="text" value="54.00000000"/>
```

En el que tengo un numero con 8 decimales. Lo que necesito es que no se puedan borrar estos decimales, pues necesito que sean siempre 8, es decir mínimo 8 decimales y máximo 8 decimales y por supuesto que no se puedan escribir letras, sino solo números y el punto antes de los decimales

Se puede conseguir esto?

Answer (score 1):

No se si sería la mejor opción, pero yo haría algo así:

```html
<label>Escribir valor:</label>
<input type="number" min="1" class="form-control item-amount" value="1.00000000" oninput="this.value = parseFloat( this.value ).toFixed(8)" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: tambien podrías intentar cambiar el método oninput por onchange  depende de ti

Comment: Modifique la pregunta amigo, coloque una imagen que describe mejor lo que trate de explicar

Answer (score 1):

Con JavaScript podrías usar

```
<input type="text" value="54.00000000" id="input">

const funcionDecimales = () => {
    input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(8);
}

input.addEventListener('blur', funcionPrueba);
```

Al escribir tu número en el input y salir de él automáticamente pondrá los 8 decimales en 0, a menos que los pongas tu mismo

Comment: Modifique la pregunta amigo, coloque una imagen que describe mejor lo que trate de explicar